# PHP: selected row from dropdown after get method

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with selected row after get method...
I have table in mysql where fill dropdown rows and I really dont know how to put option value with $_get method...
If user want to change some fields(edit it), previous row which is selected and saved needs to be selected...
This is code:

```
<label for="" style="width:100px" id="a1" >Tarifa: </label>

<?php 
$result = $db->query("select sifra, porez from porezi");
echo "<select onchange='dropdownn();' style='width:100px' id='tarifa' name='tarifa_porez' class='input-sm form-control'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    unset($sifra, $porez);
    $sifra = $row['sifra'];
    $porez = $row['porez']; 
    echo '<option value="'.$porez.'">    '.$porez.' %</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

So, this is select, but I need help to read from table which one value is selected and select it on edit link (with $_get).

Thanks guys !

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you___

Comment: `$_GET['tarifa_porez']` fetch using given code

Comment: @NishantNair but still not selecting

Comment: Check if the dropdown is in form or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is use `selected` attribute of `<option>`

So, your modified code:

```
//.. Your code...
$tarifa_porez = ! empty($_GET['tarifa_porez']) ? $_GET['tarifa_porez'] : null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($sifra, $porez);
    $sifra = $row['sifra'];
    $porez = $row['porez'];
    $selected = ($tarifa_porez == $porez) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$porez.'" ' . $selected . '>    '.$porez.' %</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

**Note:** I have used ternary operator to reduce number of lines. Please read it [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)